# Cannot validate input fields in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate

I am using vue wizard and trying to use vee-validate to validate the individual step but when i fill up the values it does not validate.

Here is a codesandbox link that i'm trying :

https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-https-oc4u2?file=/src/App.vue

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your example works for me. When I try to click next, it won't proceed to the next tab. Try to add this below the input and you'll also see an error message provided by vee-validate
`<span>{{ errors.first("title") }}</span>`

Comment: @Dan: But when i fill the value then it does not move to next tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow up to my comment. Sorry, you are right, I did not try that.

The problem is that the `validate` method is asynchronous, so the *flag* is changed only after you return it, because the validation result was not awaited.

Here is a quick fix

```
    validateFirstTab: async function () {
      let flag = await this.$validator.validate();
      return flag;
    },
```